# Multiply two different cells in MySQL

Tags: mysql, multiplication

I have a table called lynked_v1:

```
   +--------------------------------+
   | id  |   column_1  |  column_2  |  
   | -------------------------------|
   | 1   |     c1      |     c2     |
   | 2   |     c3      |     c4     |
   +--------------------------------+
```

I want to multiple c3 and c2, then set c4 as the answer.

What is the MySQL query I would use to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: You sure it is a table, and not a view?

Comment: You need to make an analytical query to solve such problem. The function you need to use is called LAG. MySql doesn't support analytical functions. Fortunately you can mimic it. See this excellent post on this subject: [Analytical functions with mysql](https://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/)

Comment: One way to do this would be a JOIN of the table with itself. Note that "c3" is actually the column aggregate when id is 2, and so on. So you would write something like `UPDATE lynked_v1 AS a JOIN lynked_v1 AS b ON ( a.id = 2 AND b.id = 1 ) SET a.inuse = a.aggregate*b.aggregate;`. For more complex functions, this approach quickly becomes a nightmare.